Spring boot using kafka container for integration tests
HI so i had a spring boot application very basic which was posting to kafka topic
I had an integration test witha container set up as follows:
  protected static final KafkaContainer KAFKA_CONTAINER =
      new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka").withTag("7.6.1")).withReuse();

What i noticed was that with reuse, the tests would take ages to run, 10 seconds or more. And sometimes they would fail on a normal run, but fine in debug. and would run fine in pipeline.
im not sure but as soon as i removed with reuse everything went super fast and it is all working fine. Any ideas why, btw i was runnign the tests locally as single test

We'd need more details on your tests please

Your issue may stem from the time required to start and stop Kafka containers, with reusability implying a wait time between each test run. By eliminating reusability, all tests run within a single Kafka container instance, reducing the time for container initiation and termination, thus accelerating test execution.
